# ExpandableList: Keep lists expanded onContentChanged()

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I use an `onContentChanged()` in an `ExpandableList` to update the `View`. Is there anyway that I can keep the `GroupViews` that the users have expanded to stay expanded?

Comment: In the method, onContentChanged() try to expand the groups using expangGroup method. But for this, you have to maintain the positions which are in open state before doing onContentChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

- In `onGroupExpand()` and `onGroupCollapse()` I keep track which groups are expanded.
- When content changes, I iterate over the groups and call `collapseGroup()` and `expandGroup()` respectively.
- Note that `expandGroup()` will result in `onGroupExpand()` and `collapseGroup()` `onGroupCollapse()` being called. You may need some flag mechanism to distinguish between user-initiated and content change initiated expand/collapse events.